# a way to store the image folder of my application with restrictions

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is a way to store the image file of my application to the mobile external storage of the mobile phone but that the galery application does not display the images contained in this folder.

Comment: You can do that just by renaming the file with no extension and those file won't show up in the gallery application

Comment: I understand your idea. Is there not a way to keep the same name with the extension of the image but to prevent gallery from displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ".nomedia" file.

Save your files to a folder that starts with ".", e.g., `/sdcard/.myimages/`

You can create .nomedia file using this code:

```
String NOMEDIA=".nomedia"; 
File Folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mydir");
   if(Folder.mkdir()) { 
      nomediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mydir/"+ NOMEDIA);
      if(!nomediaFile.exists()){
          nomediaFile.createNewFile();
      }
   }
```

**OR**

Add storage permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

```
private void hideMyFile(String original_name,String new_name)
    {
        try
        {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File from = new File(sdcard,original_name);//abc.png
        File to = new File(sdcard,new_name);//abc
        from.renameTo(to);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

So call this function `hideMyFile()` and pass two parameter and it will rename the file with no extension in this way those image will not appear in gallery

Comment: I understand your idea. Is there not a way to keep the same name with the extension of the image but to prevent gallery from displaying